# Not able to import jitpack dependencies for Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle, jitpack

I am trying to import external dependencies for implementing tables in my jetpack compose application, However whenever I try to import a dependency published with Jitpack it is showing error.

This is my build.gradle.kts (:app)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.metapointer.initprop"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.metapointer.initprop"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha08")

    
    implementation("com.github.Breens-Mbaka:BeeTablesCompose:1.1.0")


}
```

This is my build.gradle.kts (:Project)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

The error:

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTslv.png)

I tried including this in my build.gradle.kts (:Project) but it did not work

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { "https://www.jitpack.io"}

    }

}
```

Comment: Which android studio version you are using for this project?

Comment: Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using one of the latest versions of android studio. If am I  right, i recommend you to put `maven { "https://www.jitpack.io"}` to your settings.gradle file like mine below instead of putting it to root build.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
    }
}

rootProject.name = "ComposeTutorialsSevbanBayir"
include(":app")
```